# SQLServer tempDB growing infinitely

Tags: sql-server, database

we have several *"production environments"* (three servers each, with the same version of our system. Each one has a SQL Server Database as production database).

In one of this environment the *tempdb* transaction log starts to grow fast and infinitely, we can´t find why. Same version of SO, SQL Server, application. No changes in the environment.

Someone know how to figure what´s happening ou how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You might be in Full recovery model mode - if you are doing regular backups you can change this to simple and it will reduce the size of the log after the backup.

Here is [some more info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873235).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running Profiler? This will allow you to view all of the running queries on the server. This may give you some insight into what is creating items in tempdb.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to fire up SQL Server Profiler and see what's going on.  Look for high values in the "Writes" column or Spool operators, these are both likely to cause high temp usage.

If it is only the transaction log growing then try this, open transactions prevent the log from being shrunk down as it goes. This should be run in tempdb:

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think this question is the same as mine.
the tempdb grow fast. the common reason is that the programmer create the procedure, and use the temportary table.
when we create these tables, or other operation,like trigger, dbcc command, they are all use the tempdb.
create the temportary tables, sqlserver will alloc space for table, like GAM,SGAM or IAM,but sqlserver must sure the Physical consistency, so there can only be a person do it every time, the others objects must wait. that caused tempdb grow fast.
i find the sovlution from MS, about like that, hope can help you:
1.create the data files for tempdb,  the number will the same as CPU, ec:your host have 16cpu,you need to create 16 date files for tempdb. and every file must has the same size.
2.you need monitor these files , sure they are not full.
3.if these files space not enough big, that will auto grow, you need to put others the same size.

my english is not good, and if you are cant solve it, use the procedure sp_helpfile , check it. and paste the result at here.
when i was in singapore, i find this situation.
good luck.